# Can every monoid be turned into a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, monoid

It’s well-known that $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ is an example of an abelian group which is not isomorphic to the additive group of any ring.  But my question is, does there exist a monoid which is not isomorphic to the multiplicative monoid of any ring?

Or can you always find a binary operation $+$ which turns a monoid into a ring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, an obvious necessary condition for a monoid $M$ to admit a ring structure is the existence of an element $0\in M$ such that $0\cdot x=x\cdot 0=0$ for all $x\in M$ (an *absorbing* element).  This is not true of most monoids (for instance, it is not true of any nontrivial group).

Even this condition is not sufficient, though.  For instance, consider the monoid $M=\{0,1,2\}$ with operation $\min$ (so $0$ is the absorbing element and $2$ is the identity element).  This does not admit a ring structure, since the only ring with $3$ elements up to isomorphism is $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ and $M$ is not multiplicatively isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ (the non-absorbing non-identity element of $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ has an inverse, but the non-absorbing non-identity element of $M$ does not).